# iOS 5 streaming JSON endpoint

Tags: ios, json, stream

I have a project where I'd like to grab JSON data from a HTTPS endpoint.  I'm not sure if I should use NSURLConnection, NSStream, CFStream or NSJSON with stream.  I don't want to poll the connection over and over again.  This is for a chat application that connects to a server that provides the chat data via JSON.

I planned on using a UITableViewController and cells to display each message as they came in.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest NSStream. On low-level, anyways, all abstraction falls to polling...

Answer (score 1):

don't know much but 
NSURL
and then 
NSJSON

I can login and then get data. There is a youtube clip that helped me

http://www.youtube.com/watch?src_vid=9g6fDtfcd-s&feature=iv&v=Q_xrQsUZdDQ&annotation_id=annotation_731544